# String format for "2020-11-13 09:18:35+00:00"

Tags: python

I'd like to use `datetime.strptime()` to convert this string.
What's the proper format, `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ff:ff`?

`datetime.strptime("2020-11-13 09:18:35+00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+ff:ff")` is invalid.

Comment: Hint: The "+00:00" on the end is the timezone, but `f` stands for microseconds.

Comment: Also check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for the correct syntax for format strings.

Comment: You don't need `strptime`.  `datetime.fromisoformat` will handle this as-is.

Comment: The format would have been `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z"`.  `strptime` doesn't use the "yyyy-MM-dd" formats.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [format codes in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) to create proper formats.

```
print(datetime.strptime("2020-11-13 09:18:35+00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime
basedate="2017-07-05T18:38:23+00:00"
formatfrom="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"
formatto="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S= GMT+1"
```

Then, print

```
print(datetime.datime.strptime(basedate,formatfrom).strftime(formatto))
```

Check results:
[image]